# How can i select all cities belong to certain country with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

> table country - id, name, code, information, capital

> table city - id, countrycode, name

How can i show all information from a country and all its cities? capital = id, code=countrycode

So far i have this query, but doesnt work

```sql
SELECT 
  country.*, 
  country.capital as cap, 
  city.* from country 
LEFT JOIN city 
ON country.code=city.countrycode
WHERE code='usa'
```

The script above doesnt show all cities in that country and only shows capitals as number

Comment: What is the data type of `capital`?

Comment: It would help if you posted a small sample of data from each table, because the data types are important here.

Comment: capital = id = number

Comment: If capital is a number then you're going to see it three times in the results as a number because you've selected `country.*`,  `country.capital`, and `city.*` (which has city `id` in it). If you don't want that then you should explicitly select your columns from both tables and omit that field.

Answer (score 0):

So not quite sure how your data is set up but you probably want a country table and a city table and the city table has a foreign key to the country table. Maybe something like this:

```
create table Country(ID int, CapitalID int, Name Varchar(255));
create table City(ID int, CountryID int, Name Varchar(255));
```

Here is some sample data

```
insert into Country( ID, CapitalId, Name) Values (1, 1, 'USA');
insert into City (ID, CountryId, Name) Values (1,1,'Washington DC');
insert into City (ID, CountryId, Name) Values (2,1,'New York');
insert into City (ID, CountryId, Name) Values (3,1,'Seattle');
insert into City (ID, CountryId, Name) Values (4,1,'Denver');
```

Then just do a join on the foreign key:

```
 select a.Name, b.Name, Case When b.Id = a.CapitalId THEN 'True' Else 'False' End as IsCapital 
    from Country a  join City b on (b.CountryId = a.Id)
where a.Name = 'USA'
```

Result:

| Name | Name | IsCapital |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Washington DC | True |
| USA | New York | False |
| USA | Seattle | False |
| USA | Denver | False |

Here is the Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/szizi97zi9MMWEdA4ijVHX/0

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my question was little unclear, but you gave me perfect answer, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Based on the schema that you provided, just explicitly select the columns that you want like this:

```
SELECT country.id
     , country.name
     , country.information
     , country.code
     , city.name
FROM country
     LEFT JOIN city ON country.code = city.countrycode
WHERE country.code = 'usa';
```

If there are no cities in the `city` table for the country in question, then you'll still get one record with the `city.name` field as `NULL` - but I'm assuming that each country has at least its capital as an entry in the `city` table so that this situation won't arise.